# How to add test steps under Test body in nightwatch allure report?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, allure

I want  to create allure report with nightwatch framework.  allure report is created but test steps are not added under test body on report. How to do it? Any demo or anything similar would help...new to allure

Although i tried allure.createstep but didn't work with nightwatch. Below image for reference what i want....taken from https://demo.qameta.io/allure/# 
[image]